# Custom new environment positioning and margins

Tags: listings, environments, positioning, margins, newfloat

How can I place the following custom new environment at the top of every page like figures (options [ht])?

```
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Listing}

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
\begin{minted}{python}
some code
\end{minted}
\caption{Example caption}
\label{lst:label}
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

The insertion in my document is applied by placing the environment where it is written without any margin, how can I add them and improve the layout of my pages?

EDIT: for example in this page you can see the code put inside the custom environment is put at the bottom

[image]

I need to set the positioning to be at the top at the page like a figure

Comment: @campa is it clear now?

Comment: There are not captions in your example.

Comment: I'm using it just like an usual listing environment

Comment: I updated the answer. For the benefit of other readers please make your example compilable.

Answer (score 1):

Using the package `newfloat`you can define a new float with placement on top.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{kantlipsum}%  dummy tex 

\usepackage{newfloat} % added <<<<<
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!t}]{Listing} % new float <<<<   

\begin{document}

1.  \kant[1]    

\begin{Listing}
2.  \kant[2] % # 2 goes to the top of the page
\end{Listing}   

3.  \kant[3]

\end{document}
```

[image: ax]

**UPDATED** Using the new MWE posted.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}     

\usepackage{kantlipsum}%  dummy tex 

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!t}]{code} % new float <<<<

\begin{document}    
1.  \kant[1]    

\begin{code}
\begin{minted}{python}
# Solve the quadratic equation ax**2 + bx + c = 0

# import complex math module
import cmath

a = 24
b = 4
c = 46

# calculate the discriminant
d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

# find two solutions
sol1 = (-b-cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
sol2 = (-b+cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)

print('The solution are {0} and {1}'.format(sol1,sol2))
\end{minted}
\caption{Example caption}
    \label{lst:label}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

To control the position of the float, case by case.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{kantlipsum}%  dummy tex 

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Code}

\begin{document}    
1.  \kant[1]    

\begin{listing}[!t] % control the placements case by case <<<<<
\begin{minted}{python}
# Solve the quadratic equation ax**2 + bx + c = 0

# import complex math module
import cmath

a = 24
b = 4
c = 46

# calculate the discriminant
d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

# find two solutions
sol1 = (-b-cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
sol2 = (-b+cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)

print('The solution are {0} and {1}'.format(sol1,sol2)) 

\end{minted}
\caption{Example caption}
\label{lst:label}
\end{listing}   
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: how can you handle captions and environment name? Is that working with `\autoref{}`?

Comment: @Antonio Santoro Please post a short code from `\documentclass{` to `\end{document}`.  The class and the package you use are important to any solution. You could add any dummy listing of the normal length you use. (the floats do not cross page boundaries). For example you want to make a List of Listings? How do you want the listings numbered? Your document have chapters or only sections? etc.

Comment: I'm using the `minted` package to define a `code` environment

Comment: the effect of using `!t` is the environments being put at the end of the chapter and never in the same page with the text, is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: @Antonio Santoro All the floats will go to the top of the current page if fits,  or in the next page. I understood you asked for listing  always on top. If you want to have a control case by case, see my second example in the UPDATE.

Comment: However, even though the listing can't fit in the same page with the text, it will not be put in the following new page, all listings are put together at the end of the chapter

Comment: @Antonio Santoro I am sorry I am  not able guess all your requirements. Please put an complete compilable example to show the issue, with chapters and dummy text and several  listings.

Comment: Besides the previous problem, by using `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` will cause the text included in a `code` environment to not be broke in multiple pages